# Can't Access data of array Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array which is obtained form a db. I have managed to display the data in the console (I can see the data in chrome console, as shown in Picture) but for some reason no data is displayed in the actual HTML page.  *Hello* and *Hello 2* are both printed but no data is printed for {{p.price}} or {{p.propertyId}}

product.component.html

```
<table class="table" *ngIf='properties && properties.length'> 
    <tbody>
        <tr>Hello</tr>
         <tr *ngFor="let p of properties">
            <td>Hello 2</td>
            <td>{{p.price}}</td>
            <td>{{p.propertyId}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Data in Console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **array of arrays**, so you need nested `ngFor`, You can use the helper element **`<ng-container>`** like

```
<table class="table" *ngIf='properties && properties.length'> 
    <tbody>
        <tr>Hello</tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let p of properties">
         <ng-container *ngFor="let prop of p">
            <td>Hello 2</td>
            <td>{{prop.price}}</td>
            <td>{{prop.propertyId}}</td>
        </ng-container>
        </tr>
         </span>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this HTML is invalid. The only allowed direct child elements of a `tr` are `td` or `th`.

Comment: @connexo should be fine now, you can use ng-container

Comment: I haven't downvoted. And no, `span` is illegal there and creates invalid HTML.

Comment: anyways should be fine now

Comment: @Sajeetharan Thanks for the Help :) !